# Netsuite - Filter out Whole Transactions Based on Contents of Item Sublist

Tags: netsuite

I have a saved search of sales order transactions that contains both header and item sublist level information - ideally I would like the ability to filter out whole sales order based on if the item sublist of that sales order contains a specific sku/item.

My thought is that this should be fairly easy to achieve and I can do this with some kind of 'contains' formula but I cannot find any information for a situation like this online. Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction Saved Searches have Item On Any Line criteria field. Set that to "None of" and select the item(s).